# XPath query result order

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument, libxml2

For [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8193327/367456) I have created some XML related code that works on my development machine but not on viper codepad where I tested it before adding it to my answer.

I could reduce my problem to the point that the order of nodes returned by `DOMXPath::query()` differs between my system and the codepad.

XML: `<test>This is some <span>text</span>, fine.</test>`

When I query all textnodes `//child::text()` the result differs:

[**Viper Codepad:**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/x8GIHP)

```
#0: This is some 
#1: , fine.
#2: text
```

**My Machine:**

```
#0: This is some 
#1: text
#2: , fine.
```

I'm not that experienced with xpath that I do understand why this happens and how it's probably possible to influence the return order with the PHP implementation.

**Edit:**

Further testing has revealed that `LIBXML_VERSION` differs between the two systems:

```
Viper Codepad: 20626 (2.6.26; 6 Jun 2006)
My Machine...: 20707 (2.7.7; 15 Mar 2010)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could find the following bug-report which looks like the issue: [Bug 363252 - proximity position in libxml2's xmlXPathEvalExpression()](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=363252) reported 18 Oct 2006 and confirmed dating back since May 2006 which is before the 2.6.26 version in question.

This should have been fixed in libxml2 2.6.27.

Answer (score 9):

Technically XPath 1.0 returns node-sets rather than node sequences. In the XPath 1.0 specification there is no statement about the order of these node-sets - indeed, being sets, they have no intrinsic order.

However, XSLT 1.0 always processes the node-sets returned by XPath 1.0 in document order, and because of that precedent, there is a widespread expectation that XPath results will be in document order when XPath is invoked from languages other than XSLT. However, there is nothing in the spec to guarantee this. In XPath 2.0 the user expectation becomes part of the spec, and the results of a path expression MUST be in document order.

Comment: libxml2 follows the convention by design to always return in document order. Even for attributes for example which don't need to have an order as well.

Comment: @Michael Kay: What about the order with predicates? Doesn't XPath 1.0 specify the node-sets are in document order? http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates

Comment: hakre's link is broken, here's a new link for XPath 1.0 predicates: https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates
It greatly helped me in solving an unrelated problem.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like an bug in 20626 version:

It process first all child text nodes in document order, then content of child element nodes. Should be as result on your machine

Comment: While that is the most likely explanation according to Occam, there should be a bug report or an indicator in the libxml changelog then to verify that.

Comment: Where did you obtain that info from? If you can, please add a link to some official resource please.

Comment: It was only my assumption that this is an issue - because xpath results in incorrect nodes order. Currently I've found only [this](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2008-November/msg00112.html), but it is unrelated. And probably [this](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/xml/2005-May/msg00035.html) also

Comment: This is what I finally found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8195733/xpath-query-result-order/8196549#8196549

Answer (score 2):

XPath is a query language, thus it should only read the structure of the .xml document as is and never modify it. This includes the node order. In your first example however this is not true. So this is definitely a bug according to [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#data-model).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think as well, or at least how I understood the term *Document Order* in the xpath definition.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Viper Codepad is not returning the selected `text()` nodes in depth first document order, but doing a breadth first evaluation.

It is supposed to be a depth first traversal.

Saxon, MSXML, Altova XML each returned the results in a depth-first order.