# looping through all children of element with domdocument and extract text-content

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

This is the structure of a xml-file (odt-file), which I try to parse:

```
<office:body>
    <office:text>
        <text:h text:style-name="P1" text:outline-level="2">Chapter 1</text:h>
            <text:p text:style-name="Standard">Lorem ipsum. </text:p>

            <text:h text:style-name="Heading3" text:outline-level="3">Subtitle 2</text:h>
                <text:p text:style-name="Standard"><text:span text:style-name="T5">10</text:span><text:span text:style-name="T6">:</text:span><text:s/>Text (100%)</text:p>
                    <text:p text:style-name="Explanation">Further informations.</text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="Standard">9.7:<text:s/>Text (97%)</text:p>
                    <text:p text:style-name="Explanation">Further informations.</text:p>
                <text:p text:style-name="Standard"><text:span text:style-name="T9">9.1:</text:span><text:s/>Text (91%)</text:p>
                    <text:p text:style-name="Explanation">Further informations.</text:p>
                    <text:p text:style-name="Explanation">More furter informations.</text:p>
    </office:text>
</office:body>
```

With XML-Reader I did that this way:

```
while ($reader->read()){ 
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:h') { 
        if ($reader->getAttribute('text:outline-level')=="2") $html .= '<h2>'.$reader->expand()->textContent.'</h2>';
    }
    elseif ($reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->name === 'text:p') { 
        if ($reader->getAttribute('text:style-name')=="Standard") {
            $html .= '<p>'.$reader->readInnerXML().'<p>';
        }
        else if {
            // Doing something different
        }
    }
}
echo $html;
```

Now I would like to do the same thing with DOMDocument, but I need some help with the syntax. How can I loop through all children of office:text? While looping through all nodes, I would check via if/else what to do (text:h vs. text:p).

I also need to replace every text:s (if there are such elements in text:p) with a whitespace...

```
$reader = new DOMDocument();
$reader->preserveWhiteSpace  = false;
$reader->load('zip://content.odt#content.xml');

$body = $reader->getElementsByTagName( 'office:text' )->item( 0 );
foreach( $body->childNodes as $node ) echo $node->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
```

Or would it be smarter to loop through all text elements? If this is the case, still the question, how to do that.

```
$elements = $reader->getElementsByTagName('text');
foreach($elements as $node){
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
        echo $child->nodeName.': ';
        echo $child->nodeValue.'<br>';
        // check for type...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most easy ways to do that with **DOMDocument** is with the help of [**DOMXPath**](http://php.net/domxpath).

Taking your question literally:

> How can I loop through all children of office:text?

This can be represented as an [XPath expression](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
//office:text/child::node()
```

However you're using a little wrong wording here. It's not only all children, but also the children of the children and so on and so forth - that is all *descendants*:

```
//office:text/descendant::node()
```

Or with the abbreviated syntax:

```
//office:text//node()
```

Compare with: [XPath to Get All ChildNodes and not the Parent Node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5119655/367456)

For that to loop over in PHP, you need to register the namespace for the `office` prefix and then you loop over the xpath result with a `foreach`:
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($reader);
    $xpath->registerNamespace('office', $xml_namespace_uri_of_office_namespace);

```
$descendants = $xpath->query('//office:text//node()');
foreach ($descendants as $node) {
    // $node is a DOMNode as of DOMElement, DOMText, ...
}
```

XPath not in general but in PHP's libxml based libraries does return the nodes in document-order. That is the order you're looking for.

Compare with: [XPath query result order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8195733/367456)