# PHP Str_replace only within tags

Tags: php, str-replace

Ok, so I have a set of html tags that look something like this:

`<a href="whatever" title="Keyword Review">Keyword Review</a>`

`<p>Blah Blah Blah Keyword Blah Blah Blah</p>`

I want to do a str_replace of "Keyword" with `<span class="blue">Keyword</span>` but I don't want it to include the "Keyword" thats in a tag attribute, like the hyperlink title.

I was doing this:

`$content = str_replace('Keyword','<span class="blue">Keyword</span>',$content);`

but this has broken my hyperlink example:

`<a href="whatever" title="<span class="blue">Keyword</span> Review"><span class="blue">Keyword</span> Review</a>`

Can anyone suggest how I only include content within tags (any tag) but exclude the tags themselves?

Comment: If you need a robust way of doing this, you should be parsing the HTML into a DOM, iterating through that, then reassembling back into HTML at the end.

Comment: Specifically on the dupe page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8565710/2943403  I am sure Stack Overflow has several pages dedicated to this highlighting/styling task, but I only have time to find you one.

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace` instead:

```
$tag = '<a href="whatever" title="Keyword Review">Keyword Review</a>';
$content = preg_replace('/>([^>]*keyword[^<]*)</i','><span class="blue">$1</span><', $tag);
```

Comment: Please do not recommend the parsing of html with regex.  Stack Overflow has been trying to promote the reliable and professional technique of using legitimate parsing functions for this kind of task for years.

Comment: @mickmackusa, I generally agree with that sentiment, but you do have to have an entire `<html>` document to use DOMDocument, so depending on a bunch of factors, this may be the way to go. Of course, I would use PHP for JSON data and https page redirection and build the DOM on the Client... but that's me.

Comment: `but you do have to have an entire <html> document to use DOMDocument` this is simply not true.  Valid html markup is all that is required.

Comment: Your unexplained answer does not provide the required output anyhow.  https://3v4l.org/V8e0C

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach to the specific problem your propose would be to use *regular expressions* in combination with [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). For example:

```php
<?php
$subject = '<a href="whatever" title="Keyword Review">Keyword Review</a>';
$pattern = '/(?<!(?:title=\"))Keyword/';
$replacement = 'foobar';
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
var_dump($result);
```

However (and as mentioned), it is better to use API's such as [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) in order to properly filter and manage the contents of your HTML output.

Comment: Please do not recommend the parsing of html with regex.  Stack Overflow has been trying to promote the reliable and professional technique of using legitimate parsing functions for this kind of task for years.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the regular expression answers already posted is that they both look for specific tags and replace text in those tags. That's fine if only those tags are affected, but a more general approach with regexes would be difficult, if not impossible. (See [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/14853083))

A better approach is to use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML file, and use [DOMXpath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) to search for the text nodes and attributes that need to be changed.

```
<?php
    $dd = new DOMDocument();
    $dd->loadHTMLFile('test.html');

    $dx = new DOMXPath($dd);

    // find all the text nodes
    $tn = $dx->query('//text()');

    foreach($tn as $textNode) {
        $textNode->nodeValue = str_replace('Keyword', 'NewWord', $textNode->nodeValue);
    }

    // Look for all the title attributes
    $tn = $dx->query('//@title');
    foreach($tn as $textNode) {
        $textNode->nodeValue = str_replace('Keyword', 'NewWord', $textNode->nodeValue);
    }

    $dd->saveHTMLFile('test2.html');
```

Input file `test.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test HTML file to test keyword replacement with DOMDocument</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>a keyword in a paragraph</p>
<div class="keyword">A keyword in a div, with a class of keyword</div>
<a href="keyword.html">Keyword in an anchor</a>

<a href="whatever" title="Keyword Review">Keyword Review</a>

<p>Blah Blah Blah Keyword Blah Blah Blah</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Output file `test2.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test HTML file to test keyword replacement with DOMDocument</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>a keyword in a paragraph</p>
<div class="keyword">A keyword in a div, with a class of keyword</div>
<a href="keyword.html">NewWord in an anchor</a>

<a href="whatever" title="NewWord Review">NewWord Review</a>

<p>Blah Blah Blah NewWord Blah Blah Blah</p>

</body>
</html>
```

More refined searches can be performed by using more sophisticated XPath queries.

This simple demonstrator is case-sensitive, so `Keyword` is replaced, but `keyword` is not. There's also no attempt to match case so that `keyword` would be replaced by `newWord`, but `Keyword` is replaced by `NewWord`, and `KEYWORD` is replaced by `NEWWORD`, for example.