# jQuery highlighting of HTML which includes text formatting tags

Tags: php, jquery, regex, dom, highlighting

There are a number of jQuery text highlighting routines (plugins) available, such as the ones offered by Johann Burkard and Bartek Szopka, but all of the ones I've found so far fail to highlight any text which includes HTML text formatting tags.

For example, if I wish to highlight the phrase *"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"* and the HTML page contains the phrase `Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit amet`, then that occurrence of the phrase is not highlighted.

Similarly, if I wish to highlight the word *"Lorem"* and the HTML page contains `Lo<i>rem</i>`, then that occurrence is also not highlighted.

I started out using a regex in PHP to do the highlighting, but virtually everyone said it's impossible to reliably highlight without going to the DOM, so now I've gone to the DOM, and apparently using the DOM has great difficulties too!

Can anybody suggest either a better jQuery highlighting routine or a modification to an existing routine which will solve this difficulty?

Comment: As far as PHP is concerned, this question has been answered here: [Ignore html tags in preg_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8193327/367456) - the same should be possible with javascript as well.

Comment: @hakre in the article you mention, the example on codepage.viper-7 seems to be not working. Is there any place to view or download the complete working code for your example?

Comment: Yes, it's on github as well: https://gist.github.com/gists/1894360/ - was linked there in the comments. The example is in the answer IIRC.

Comment: @hakre -- Thank you, but I remain a bit bewildered. In your skeleton example code, after processing the search results, how does one obtain the "output" xml?

Comment: Or HTML. I think there is a jquery highlight plugin that works with HTML well. I used it in the [Admin Quicksearch Wordpress Plugin](http://hakre.wordpress.com/plugins/admin-quicksearch/).

Comment: @hakre... I have your php code all gathered together (from github and from your stackoverflow answer "skeleton") for testing, but I do not understand where to obtain the "output" after the tags have been added in your example code. You show an example of the html output with the new span tags added, but I do not understand where/how to obtain that revised html output in php.  Could you please clarify?

Comment: In PHP? For PHP, use the DOMDocument based example, not the wordpress plugin. The wordpress plugin is pure javascript highlighting.

Comment: @hakre...javascript was my initial question at stackoverflow.com/questions/10092886/jquery-highlighting-of-html-which-includes-text-formatting-tags but since the existing jquery routines which I found do not seem to be capable of highlighting phrases which include html formatting tags, you suggested your php solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193327/ignore-html-tags-in-preg-replace . Do you know of a jquery plugin which solves that problem?

Comment: Doesn't the one in the my wordpress plugin does that? It's some jQuery plugin I don't remember the name any longer (and I think I've hacked it for multiple color support).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not very concerned about the existing formatting, you can use:

```
 $('selector').html($('selector').text());
```

then apply your highlighter.

Comment: Applying a highlight to a formatted HTML is possible, but needs to write a plugin, not a simple answer here.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, but for this web page highlighting, it is important to retain any existing text formatting.