# preg_replace with pattern and html tags not working

Tags: php

i have this:

```
<span style="color:#ff8c00;"><strong>Benjamin Franklin</strong></span>
or
<span style="color:#ff8c00;"><strong><em>Benjamin Franklin</em></strong></span>
or
<span style="color:#ff8c00;">Benjamin Franklin</span>
```

i need returns:

```
[color=#ff8c00]<strong>Benjamin Franklin</strong>[/color]
[color=#ff8c00]<strong><em>Benjamin Franklin</em></strong>[/color]
[color=#ff8c00]Benjamin Franklin[/color]
```

I have this pattern in PHP

```
~<span\s[^>]*\bstyle=[\'\"]color\:([\#a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\,]+)\;[\'\"]>([\<a-z0-9\>]+)(.+?)\s([\<\/a-z0-9\>]+)<\/span>~is
```

but not works well, allthough in RegExr show is works http://regexr.com/3bjis

this returns me in PHP:

```
[/[color=#Benjamin Franklin
```

PHP

```
$text = preg_replace(
    array(
        '~<span\s[^>]*\bstyle=[\'\"]color\:([\#a-zA-Z0-9\(\)\,]+)\;[\'\"]>([\<a-z0-9\>]+)(.+?)([\<\/a-z0-9\>]+)<\/span>~is',    
    ),
    array(
      '[color=$1]$2$3$4[/color]',
    ), ltrim($text));

echo $text;
```

regards.

EDIT: My question is very different, my pattern works very well in RegExr link above posted, but in PHP echoing returns incorrectly, really I would not resort to using XPath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ignore html tags in preg\_replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193327/ignore-html-tags-in-preg-replace)

Comment: "echoing returns incorrectly" - well, look at the source, not the browser rendering, or escape HTML.

Comment: You haven't provided your PHP source - the regex alone isn't enough: how are you using it?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol My mistake, question edited.

Comment: This snippet of your regex `(.+?)` is almost certainly wrong. Did you mean `(.*)` instead?

Comment: Thanks @BenRoux, still returning ´[/[/[color=#Benjamin Franklin´

Comment: @BenRoux Why the heck is that "almost certainly wrong"? I'd consider it "almost certainly right"...

Comment: I tested your code. It works just fine...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Really? why in my code returns that? In RegExr works fine but in my PHP code not :S

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. Html is not regular

Comment: @Ibu is not fully html is just plain text from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't easy but this may do what you want.

```
'<span.+?style=(\'|\")color\:(.+?)\1[^>]*>(.+?)(?=\<\/span\>)<\/span>'
```

And for the replacement

```
'[color=$2]$3[/color]'
```

https://regex101.com/r/rE1oR3/4

To explain

- `\<span` match literal
- `.+?` match anything non-greedy
- `style=` match literal
- `(\'|\")` match single or double quote, capture group 1 we'll use this latter
- `color: match literal
- `(.+?)` match and capture anything non-greedy
- `\1` backrefrence the quote style previously matched
- `[^>]*` match anything ( including empty ) that is not a >
- `>` match literal
- `(.+?)` match and capture anything non-greedy
- `(?=\<\/span\>)` positive lookahead anchors the non-greedy match, much like the `style=` or the `\1` bits do but makes sure it matches the first `</span>` it encounters.
- `<\/span>` match literal